# Throwing error with using CircleImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am absolute beginner to Android. Now I am learning how to design an Android App. So now I am trying to use CircleImageView. I installed it using gradle. But when I use it in Layout file, it is throwing error.

This is my xml layout file with CircleImageView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <CircleImageView
        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Your to-do list"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I installed CircleImageView using compile in Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.waiyanhein.todo.todo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

But when I run it, it is throwing error.

This is the Logcat:

```
01-28 08:54:08.499 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-28 08:54:08.499 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6152908)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.waiyanhein.todo.todo/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class CircleImageView
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:190)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:250)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CircleImageView" on path: /data/app/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo-1.apk
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:190) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:250) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-28 08:54:08.503 29509-29509/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is wrong with my code, and is that a correct way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your xml replace `CircleImageView` to `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView`

[link](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

**FINAL CODE**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Your to-do list"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your xml change `CircleImageView` to `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView`

like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Your to-do list"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```